# Sort Month+Year in VB.net using MS-ACCESS as db

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am using following query

```
select month(datee) as [Month], year(datee) as [Year]
from ledger_broker
group by month(datee),year(datee)
```

Output :
 [image: Output]

What's the query to combine both columns and show as

```
1-2016
2-2016
```

OR

```
Jan-2016
Feb-2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Format()` expression to format the month plus year as you wish.  For months as digits, this should work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Format(datee, 'm-yyyy') AS month_year
FROM ledger_broker
ORDER BY Month(datee), Year(datee);
```

For abbreviated month names, adjust the `Format` pattern:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Format(datee, 'mmm-yyyy') AS month_year
```